# jquery equivalent of php 'if ip equals' condition?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'd like to know, can the following PHP 'if' conditions can be done in jquery?

```
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '123.99.55.616') {
      // public doingness
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '123.99.55.616') {
      // self doingness
    }
```

Or javascript, but preferably jquery; thanks.

(Of course, if I could run these PHP snippets from within a JS file that would suit me just fine, but all the reading I've done so far leads me to believe it might not be doable.)

Comment: I believe `data.host` would give you the ip(where `data` is the object returned by a successful ajax call)

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonip.com's json response.

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com",
    function(data){
       alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
  });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/q2Ece/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an url formatted with the callback=? parameter to the $.getJSON method to get IP Remote IP Address, for example:

```
 $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
       alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
  });
```

Hope will help!

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER is a php variable and it will not use in jquery, but you can store its value in some html element and then can fetch into jquery

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can get remote address with the below code

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
alert(data.ip);
});
```